# CodedUI does not run with SpecFlow 2.1

Tags: coded-ui-tests, specflow, gherkin

We have a code only CodedUI project which we use for GUI testing and now we are investigating the possibility of using SpecFlow Feature files. So I:

1. Created inside this CodedUI project a subfolder 'Gherkin'
2. Installed nuget SpecFlow 2.1
3. Installed nuget SpecFlow.MsTest
4. Added to the folder of step 0 a feature file and generated the C# code.

Now when I embed inside the first Gherkin C# Method, a simple CodedUI statement which opens the browser I get a 'filenotfoundexception: could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility'

When I uninstall 2.1 and install SpecFlow 1.9 with SpecFlow.plugins.codedui it works without problems!

Is there a solution for 2.1?

Comment: I would consider an alternative to spec flow which is hand written page objects.  http://codeduiexamples.com/ http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and we luckily already use POM's. Our MTM integration is from a business perspective not very readable and we noticed MTM is rather user unfriendly. SpecFlow integration would be a major advantage.

Comment: I agree that MTM is not user friendly.  :(  Page objects with properly named tests have been successful for us.  Hope everything goes well for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SpecFlow 2.1 we changed the plugin infrastructure and so older plugins do not work anymore.

But it is not difficult to implement the needed stuff for CodedUI on your own.
Please see https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-SpecFlow-with-CodedUI-API

The documentation is not yet updated to SpecFlow 2.*, but the interfaces did not have changed. You have to adapt the paths to the new version numbers.

If you have questions, please join us on our Gitter- Channel.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Although I found this link some days ago I did not know I could use it for 2.1. My plan is to try out your project using version1.9 and wait for updated documentation.